# Should I perform Linear Discriminant Analysis over the entire dataset for dimensionality reduction?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, dimensionality-reduction

I don't understand how to use LDA just for dimensionality reduction.

I have a 75x65 matrix with 64 features and 1 column for the class index. This matrix can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/ZJ3E90k7).

I am trying to use LDA for dimensionality reduction, using [this function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis) from sklearn.

```
def classify(featureMatrix):
    X, y = featureMatrix[:, :63], featureMatrix[: ,64]
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,  y, test_size=0.20)
    lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, criterion="gini", max_depth=20)

    X_train = lda.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
    X_test = lda.transform(X_test)

    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print rf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

However, my classification score is usually low (20-30%). The problem seems to be when I transform the test data.

For example, when I plot X_train after the dimensionality reduction I have:

[image]

Which has good class separation.

But when I transform the test set and plot X_test, I have this:

[image]

Which has no apparent pattern and is far from what we could see in our training dataset.

I hypothesise that this could be a result of a small dataset (only 75 samples equally distributed in 5 classes), but this data is really difficult to gather unfortunately.

I've read from different places people using LDA over all the dataset before trying to separate the dataset in training/test sets and classify it with another classifier (This way I could achieve less than 10% of error), but I also heard a lot of people saying I should use the way I mentioned in the code. If I am only using LDA for dimensionality reduction, which way is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this spectacular [repository/book](https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/blob/master/code/ch06/ch06.ipynb) you should fit LDA over the training dataset and then transform both training and testing datasets using the smaller fitted before.